# resteasy, jaxb - How to produce a collection/list of strings?

Tags: java, jaxb, resteasy

Simple task, I need to produce this XML:

```
<collection>
    <name>bill</name>
    <name>monica</name>
<collection>
```

instead of this (see following example: [19.6. Arrays and Collections of JAXB Objects](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html_single/#JAXB_Collections)):

```
<collection>
    <customer><name>bill</name></customer>
    <customer><name>monica</name></customer>
<collection>
```

Simple collection with strings. So the question is how to remove surrounding `customer` element? How can I do this with RESTeasy and JAXB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `Customer` class map the name property with the `@XmlValue` annotation:

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;

    @XmlValue
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've forgot about your blog, I should look there first :-) But the life is not easy I get now following exception: `@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class`. I've try with `@XmlTransient` on superclass but it is not working, any ideas?

Comment: @XmlTransient should fix your problem (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html).  Does you super class have any properties that are mapped to XML elements?  Do you know which implementation of JAXB you are using (What is the result of `jaxbContextInstance.getClass()`)?

Comment: `@XmlTransient` on super class fixed the problem, it is working now as I expect. Thanks.